# Проблема с формами в Django 2.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-3.6

Учу Django по документации к 2.1, пишу пример-голосование, но возникла проблема с формами. На странице имеется вопрос и кнопка голосования, но не отображаются варианты ответа, которые реализованы в виде RadioButton. В чём ошибка и как исправить проблему?

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import Question
from .models import Choice

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = {
    'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


def detail(request, question_id):
    try:
        question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
    except Question.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Question does not exist")
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice =      question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
    # Redisplay the question voting form.
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
        'question': question,
        'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
    })
else:
    selected_choice.votes += 1
    selected_choice.save()
    # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
    # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
    # user hits the Back button.
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

detail.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="/polls/{{question.id}}/vote/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text  }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

results.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

index.html

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Comment: А где forms.py? Или вы делаете формы без forms.py?

Comment: Без forms.py, да.

Comment: Почитайте про формы в джанго. Обычно использую их.